# assigning a variable to a value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a variable (paddleOneVelocityY) that I want to change to one of the values in an array ( paddleSpeeds), based on the position of the value of another variable (trialWindow) in another array (trialValues).

This code would mean that the value of paddleOneVelocityY would change if the value of trialWindow appears in the trialValues array, and its position in the array would determine which value from paddleSpeeds would be assigned to paddleOneVelocityY. For example, if trialWindow's value is the 3rd value in trialValues, the 3rd value in paddleSpeeds would be assigned as the new value of paddleOneVelocityY.

So far, I have written code to identify whether a value appears in the trialValues array and change the paddle colour based on this which is working but I've only put a random number placeholder to change paddleOneVelocityY. I'm guessing I'll need to write more code to identify the index of the value of trialWindow in trialValues and then use that index to assign the value at the same index in paddleSpeeds to paddleOneVelocityY, I'm just not sure how to implement this...

```
const trialValues = [30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210];
const paddleSpeeds = [5, 20, 30, 10, 5, 15, 25];

function includes(array, searchElement) {
        for (let element of array)
        if (element === searchElement)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


function userSpeed() {
    if (includes(trialValues, trialWindow))
    {colourChange = '#ff00ff', paddleOneVelocityY = getRandomNumber(5, 35), console.log({paddleOneVelocityY})}
else {colourChange = 'white'}
```

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, [array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) already exists in javascript

Comment: Yeah, I found that out after I'd written the function but didn't bother updating the code. I'm very much a beginner so often do things the hard way by accident!

Answer (score 0):

Use indexOf :

```
const index = trialValues.indexOf(120); // will return 3
```

then

```
paddleSpeeds[index] = 'newValue';
```